# Trouble implementing a Garch 1,1 Model for financial time series

Tags: matlab

I want to estimate adjust a volatility weighted time series of returns with a Garch 1,1 model in MATLAB. When I run the code, however, using the standard MATLAB functions I hit a wall in generating the proper return vectors I'm looking for to build off of it further.

Does anyone have a Garch 1,1 model that can run within a function and output the adjusted volatility series as a vector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's the model

```
function [vols] = modelGarchVol(omega, beta, alpha, returns)
    variance_vec = zeros(length(returns), 1);
    variance_vec(2) = returns(1)^2;
    for i=3:length(variance_vec)
        variance_vec(i) = omega + alpha*returns(i-1)*returns(i-1) + beta*variance_vec(i-1);
    end
    variance_vec;
    mean(variance_vec);
    vols = variance_vec(2:end).^(1/2);
```

and the garch vol

```
function [params,fval] = garchVol(initial_params, returns)

    A = [0 1 1];
    b = [1];
    [params, fval] = fmincon(@maxGarchParams, initial_params, A, b, [], [], [0 0 0]);
    
    function [logLikelihood] = maxGarchParams(params_vec)
        omega = params_vec(1);
        beta = params_vec(2);
        alpha = params_vec(3);

        variance_vec = zeros(length(returns), 1);
        variance_vec(2) = returns(1)^2;
        
        logLikelihood = 0;
        for i=3:length(variance_vec)
            variance_vec(i) = omega + alpha*returns(i-1)*returns(i-1) + beta*variance_vec(i-1);
            logLikelihood = logLikelihood + (-log(variance_vec(i)) - ((returns(i)*returns(i))/variance_vec(i)));
        end
        logLikelihood = logLikelihood*-1;
    end
end
```